# Does a differentiable surjective function $f: [0, \infty) \mapsto [0,1]$ exist?

Tags: calculus, general-topology

> Does a differentiable surjective function $f: [0, \infty) \mapsto [0,1]$ exist?

It is fairly easy to create a surjective function that does the mapping, but when it comes to deciding whether a diferentiable one exists, the question gets quite tricky. I am rather inclined to say that such function does not exist, because we would never get the same slope from the left and from the right - because we would have to manually adjust the slope from one side, for example: 
$$f(x) = \cases{\sqrt x &$: x<1$ \\ 1 &$:x \ge 1$ }$$
would have the slope of $1/2$ from the left and $0$ from the right. 

Is there a formal way to solve this problem?

Comment: Instead of sqrt.x take x

Comment: ^ That’s not differentiable at 1 though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course $f(x)=\sin ^2(x)$. And this is not the only one you can imagine.

Comment: So simple, it’s great.  +1

Comment: Or $(1+\sin x)/2$. `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

What about $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$?